# Acer problem with sparse leaf growth

Tags: trees, tree-care

I have a japanese acer that I have had in my garden for over 40 years and every year it has produced good leaf growth, until this year. I have seen some lichens on the branches which I haven't noticed before and wondered if this has any bearing on the problem. I can post photos to show the problem, but cannot see anyway to post them